# Laravel 5 using pivot table with hasMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm making a poll system and I have two tables :

- **`polls`** table : Has those fields (`id,question,created_at,updated_at`).
- **`choices`** table : Has those fields (`id,poll_id,choice`).

And a pivot table named **`choice_poll`** : Has those fields (`id,choice_id,poll_id,ip,name,phone, comment ,created_at,updated_at`)

**Poll Model :**

```
class Poll extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'polls';
    protected $fillable = ['question'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function choices()
    {
      return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Choice')->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment');
    }
}
```

**Choice Model :**

```
class Choice extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'choices';
    protected $fillable = ['poll_id','choice'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function poll()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Poll')->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment');
    }
}
```

Now  when I try to build this query it doesn't return the choices :

```
$poll->first()->choices()->get()
```

**PS:** There is many choices in the choices table associated with the first poll.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you have **[Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)** relationship so try to change `belongsTo` in :

```
public function poll()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Poll')->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment');
}
```

To `belongsToMany`, and it will be :

```
public function poll()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Poll')->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment');
}
```

**NOTE 1:** You have to change `BelongsToMany` to `belongsToMany` note the `B` should be in lower case.

**NOTE 2:** You want the pivot table with timestapms  `create_at,updated_at` as you mentioned in th OP so you have to use `withTimestamps();` :

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Poll')
            ->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment')
            ->withTimestamps();

//AND in the other side also

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Choice')
            ->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment')
            ->withTimestamps();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
public function poll()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Poll')->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment');
}
```

and

```
public function choices()
{
  return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Choice')->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment');
}
```

should be:

```
public function poll()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Poll')->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment');
}
```

and

```
public function choices()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Choice')->withPivot('ip','name','phone','comment');
}
```

Comment: but the choice belongs only to one poll not many !!
by the way evenif i changed the code as you mentioned nothing happend